# HTML5 local storage Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage

I try to implement now a local Storage in Angular2 for the first time and get a bit confused.

So, I have First Component, where I register my user

```
export class FormComponent {
  modus = ['first', 'second'];
  model: User = new User('', '', '');
  constructor(private _cookieService: CookieService) {}
}
```

Here is class, that I use in `FormComponent`

```
export class User {
  constructor (
    public email: string,
    public name: string,
    public modus: string
  ) {}
}
```

I bind it and everything in form works very good.
Now I want to store it in local storage (3 parameters of `User`)

But how could I do this?

I leave this page with registration of user and go to other pages, like

```
export class Part1Component {
  public email;
  public name;
  public modus;

  constructor(private _location: Location) {}
     myTestFunction(){

    /* assign values here
       this.email = ;
       this.name = ;
       this.modus = ;
   */
       }


 }
```

How could I get values from storage and assign them here?

Comment: Have you heard of `localStorage.setItem()` and `localStorage.getItem()`? If not, I suggest a bit of googling first

Comment: Does the user data need to be saved between instances? if not then i would create an injectable class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you storing a user object in session storage by using `JSON.stringify()` then you can do this

```
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
this.email=user.email;
this.name=user.name;
```

Answer (score 5):

Typescript provides `localStorage` which you can use to set and get storage data.

> Use the `localStorage.setItem(key, value);` method where you want to
>   set the data.

```
localStorage.setItem('__user__email', user.email);
localStorage.setItem('__user__name', user.name);
localStorage.setItem('__user__modus', user.modus);
```

> .. and `localStorage.getItem(key);` where you want to get the data.

```
myTestFunction() {

    // assign values here
    this.email = localStorage.getItem('__user__email');
    this.name  = localStorage.getItem('__user__name');
    this.modus = localStorage.getItem('__user__modus');
}
```

---

You can have a look at this utility class and use that I created in one of my projects:

> [**LOCAL STORAGE UTILITY CLASS**](https://gist.github.com/faisalmuhammad/674c902c1f094077c44edbe0095b6e64)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `localStorage.setItem()` to save your data and `localStorage.getItem()` to get your saved data from localStorage. Please read this [localStorage Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for more details.

Here is a simple example for using localStorage.

Save data to localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('userKey', JSON.stringify(this.model));
```

Beware that you can save only strings to localStorage.

Get saved data from localStorage for your Example:

```
let savedUser: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userKey'));
```

If you want to clear or remove saved data you can use following code:

```
localStorage.removeItem('userKey');
```

or

```
localStorage.clear();
```

You can request your data from every point to localStorage in your application.

Answer (score 0):

use html5 localStorage
like this

localStorage.setItem("key",value)
set a item and then you can get it even you close the borwser.

localStorage.getItem("key");

and it save as string